# What version of windows server to run coldfusion web server on local lan?

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'd like to install Windows Server on an old desktop pc to act as a small web server for our lan.  With all the variations available, not sure which one would be ideal:

1. Windows Server Standard 2008
2. Windows Server Standard 2008 R2
3. Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 with SP1
4. Windows Server Standard 2008 with Service Pack 2
5. Windows Server Standard 2008 without Hyper-V
6. Windows Server Standard 2012
7. Windows Small Business Server Essentials 2011
8. Windows Web Server 2008 <-- overkill?

Is there a better version of Windows server we could use or would Windows 7 be just fine to act as a CF10 web server?  We don't care if the web server is running iis, apache, or tomcat.

Comment: When all else fails, read the manual.  

http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-standard/tech-specs.html

Comment: Question is better suited for Serverfault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need to install Windows Server on your pc, to use it as webserver. You can simply install **IIS 6/7/7.5** as per the compatibility of your system.

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like we'll just restore the system with its native OS of Windows 7 Pro and go from there.